# Should objects know about their users in certain cases?

Tags: encapsulation, information-hiding

I'm laying out the foundations for a potential game, but I'm having trouble designing the classes to be encapsulated yet efficient.

Generally, people say objects should rely little on each other to preserve modularity and encapsulation.

However, sometimes it seems convenient to have some object know about each other.

Let's say we have a class called Dog.

```
public class Dog {

  public void eat() { ... }
  public void wagTail() { ... }

}
```

Dogs have owners, so there is a dog owner class.

```
public class DogOwner {
  private Dog dog;

  public Dog getDog() { return dog; }
  public void petDog() { ... }
  public void takeDogForWalk() { ... }
}
```

Now, what if we have a `Dog`, but we don't have its owner?  It seems to make sense to make a `getOwner()` method for `Dog`.

```
public class Dog {
  private DogOwner owner;

  public void eat() { ... }
  public void wagTail() { ... }
  public DogOwner getOwner() { return owner; }

}
```

However, this now gives `Dog` information about the `DogOwner`, which seems to violate information hiding.  It also seems to create redundancy, because `Dog` has a `DogOwner`, and `DogOwner` has a `Dog`.

Another way to find the owner is to simply look through all the owners, and find the corresponding dog.  Though this will not create dependency of `Dog` and `DogOwner`, this seems a lot more expensive than it needs to be, because we have to cycle through all the owners.

So, is it alright for `Dog` to have a `getOwner()` method?  If it is not, what other alternatives are there to efficiently access the owner if only the `Dog` is known?

Comment: it is a reciprocical relation. the dog does not have the same behavior toward its owner it has toward the rest of the world. On the other hand, if you are in a context where you have a reference to the dog, do you not have a reference to the owner at the same time? (or can you actually access the dog directly, without going through its owner?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Should rely little" - just as much as is needed, not more, not less.

Of course the dog can have a link to its owner. You asked about the alternatives: One, to always carry the dog and the owner information together, even when lots of code doesn't care about the owner. Two, if you have a dog and don't know the owner, you obviously can't ask the owner. You could have a hash table mapping dogs to owners, but then you might as well just store the dog with the owner. Or you have a database of all dog owners and scan it for an owner of that dog - not exactly scaleable.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not a software design pragmatist, I don't see how this would necessarily violate too many design principles. For `Dog` to "know" anything about `DogOwner` it still needs to access `DogOwner`'s methods. So, you're not saying `Dog.getDogOwnersName` or something like that, you would say `Dog.getOwner().getName()`. This way, all `Dog` cares about is who its owner is. But any information beyond that is effectively still hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's alright to do this.  One alternative that comes to mind though would be to use a dictionary with Dog as the key and DogOwner as the value (since hypothetically the DogOwner could change over time).  This would also have an added benefit of keeping one central repository of Dog/DogOwner relationships.